# chrome.runtime.sendMessage not working

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension, and I'm running into this really annoying problem. I would like to send a message from my content script to the background and send a response back.

I keep getting this error:

> Port: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

I'm currently using this code.

background:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse){
    sendResponse("got it!");
});
```

content script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(<extension id>, "test message", function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

I'm using chrome version 30.0.1599.69 m.

Answer (score 0):

in Content script, here I don't have "extension id", just message and callback function, so it's default sending the message to this extension rather that any other extension in google chrome:

```
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "removeCookie"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.farewell);
    });
```

in background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){

        if (message.greeting == "removeCookie"){
                    //remove cookie
                    //...

              sendResponse({farewell:"cookie clean"});

        }

});
```